# Kid-friendly tiling window manager

Tags: x11, window-managers, tiling, logo-lang

I am looking for a tiling window manager that will allow my daughter (4 yrs) to run `ucblogo` and display the turtle graphics at the same time.

A little background:

Ubuntu/Debian has a package `ucblogo`, which runs from the console or, graphically, from within X. Running it from within X allows, besides others, for the `showturtle` command which will show the logo-turtle. The turtle is shown in it's own window and the input has it's own window (usually the `xterm` `ucblogo` is started from). The graphics window is only "started" once the logo command `showturtle`has been issued, ie. it's not there from the beginning on. See this partial screenshot from the raspberry (in which the turtle is not shown, it's in the `BXLogo` window on the right):

[image: screenshot1]

The whole setup is running under a raspberry pi for now, but I'd like to give her her own netbook I have lying around (and yes, it will only be used under "supervision" ;).

The concept of tiling winow managers is a bit strange to me, yet am I looking for a tiling window manager that allows me to display both windows. Starting with the text.input window, then the second window with graphics should be above.

Could anyone please point me to a beginner's resource on how to set up a tiling window manager to do the above (start with one, fullscreen `xterm`, then, upon the second window coming into existence, tiling this window above or besides the first).

I have tried `ratposion` before but that seems to tile only manually and I have looked into `xmonad` but that has 400 megs of dependencies and the netbook only has about that much free.

A little more educational background:

The reason I want a tiling window manager is that I want to keep all the mouse/touchpad crud away from her for the time being. She can already log in with her username and password, so the concept of using the keyboard is a bit closer then that of a mouse. Also the netbook only has a resolution of 800x480 pixels so I do not want to loose any space on fancy decorations.

Comment: This sure doesn't _sound_ like a programming question. Are you writing code yourself, or just trying to set up software?

Comment: Looks like something you should be asking on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/) or [unix](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchanges.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into `i3`. It features tiling window management and easy to setup keybindings. However, for a young child, a tiling window manager may be too much for their understanding, you may consider your sanity.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; for a young child a tiling manager IMHO has a lot of advantages; mostly it offers a fairly distraction-free interface. No shiny buttons, nothing flimsy to move around. One thing at a time seems to be actually a good way to to for them.